# Add CClayer(HUD layer) at top on OpenGLView?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

i am creating a game which has a **HUD layer** on top showing scores and stuff.
The main game screen window is movable  during the game so i cant add the HUD layer directly as it starts to move alongwith the game window and goes offscreen.
So i want to add the HUD layer to the top on game window .how can i achieve that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can imagine, you have game screen window as `CCLayer` object. So, create new `CCLayer`, add it to your scene above game screen and add HUD into it. Otherwise please share your code.

Comment: got it thanx.. i added two layers to the scene in +(id) scene method which worked and is the right method i guess